# R boxplot several variables at once

Tags: r, boxplot

I have the following data set that I would like to make a boxplot from:

```
July<-c("Closed","Open")
Cistus<-c(10.8, 18.9)
CS<-c(2.004, 3.9)
Oak<-c(7.4, 12.4)
OS<-c(0.9,2.1)

df<-data.frame(July, Cistus, CS, Oak, OS)
```

I would like my boxplot to have Cistus and Oak at the x-axis, each with two boxes (opened and closed). So in total 4 boxes....

I am epically failing at this... Please can you help me? I'm sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modification of Vincent's code but with the subsetting to the desired categories:

```
library(reshape2)
#reshape into long format
dfnew<-melt(df, "July")
#subset down to just Cistus and Oak
dfnew<-droplevels(dfnew[dfnew$variable %in% c("Cistus", "Oak"),])
#plot
boxplot(value ~ July+variable, data=dfnew, las=2, col=c("grey10", "grey50"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I was asking for a friend and looks like its working now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using `reshape2` to arrange your data.frame. Then, you can use formula in boxplot, so:

```
library(reshape2)
boxplot(July + variable ~ value, melt(df))
```

With more than one value per group and some color:

```
df2 <- data.frame(July=rep(c("Closed", "Open"), each=5),
                  Cistus=runif(10),
                  CS=runif(10),
                  Oak=runif(10),
                  OS=runif(10))

boxplot(value ~ July + variable, melt(df2), col=c("grey10", "grey50"))
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: hm... this is not exactly what I am looking for. Basically I am ignoring CS and OS at this stage... But looking for Cistus.Open, Cistus.Closed, Oak.Open and Oak.closed....

Comment: Thank you nevertheless for your answer!